# Deviceready is not working in cordova

Tags: cordova

Deviceready is not working in cordova when i remove the plugins its working fine.
my plugin list

```
 "org.apache.cordova.device": "0.2.12-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.network-information": "0.2.12-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.battery-status": "0.2.11-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.device-motion": "0.2.10-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.device-orientation": "0.3.9-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.geolocation": "0.3.10-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.media": "0.2.13-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.file-transfer": "0.4.6-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.contacts": "0.2.13-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.globalization": "0.3.1-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.splashscreen": "0.3.3-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser": "0.5.2-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.console": "0.2.11-dev",
"org.apache.cordova.camera": "0.3.2-dev",
"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode": "0.5.0",
"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "0.7.4",
"org.transistorsoft.cordova.plugin.background.fetch": "2.0.2",
"nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing": "4.3.7",
"org.apache.cordova.file": "1.3.0"
```

Comment: Remove one plugin at a time until you find the problem file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT your problem you just need to do is 
update the following plugin 
"org.apache.cordova.file": "1.3.0"
the problem will resolve